# Failed to apply mutation locally : {}

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra version 3.9 (https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/4bb926527d4a9eb534508fe0bbae604dee81f40a/3.9/Dockerfile)
It happened when I added 2 node to cluster, and this error occurs only in this 2 node with periodicity every 2 minutes. I done repair for all cluster, but it didn't help. It's occur while Cassandra is running.

See this error on 2 of 3 nodes in a cluster.

```
ERROR 07:13:44 Failed to apply mutation locally : {}
java.nio.BufferOverflowException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBufferFixed.doFlush(DataOutputBufferFixed.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        ...
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Please fill a ticket in the [Cassandra JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) including the whole stack trace.

Comment: please include more information, version, platform, or anything at all about what you were doing. is this startup? while running? shutdown? does it repeat or happen just once?

Comment: I updated description

Answer (score 1):

Even I came across the same error. The answer lies here

[Mutation of  bytes is too large for the maxiumum size of](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207267063-Mutation-of-x-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-y-)

It was not present in datastax help center when the question was posted, but added a year later. Hope it helps